# Bower : can't install dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

when i try to install angular-sails i'm getting error :

```
λ bower install
bower angular-sails#*       not-cached https://github.com/kyjan/angular-sails.git#*
bower angular-sails#*          resolve https://github.com/kyjan/angular-sails.git#*
bower angular-mocks#~1.5.0  not-cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.5.0
bower angular-mocks#~1.5.0     resolve https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.5.0
bower angular-scenario#~1.5.0       not-cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#~1.5.0
bower angular-scenario#~1.5.0          resolve https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#~1.5.0
bower angular-sails#*                  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/kyjan/angular-sails.git", exit code of #128
```

Answer (score 0):

Check port 22 isn't blocked on your computer and try the install again.

Also, you could try the following:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

to tell git to use HTTPS instead of GIT which worked out for me to install npm dependencies.

Comment: You copy and paste exactly what I wrote.

Comment: i use it but nothing changing

Comment: You won't see anything change. But next time you run the `bower install` it will use `https://` instead of `git://`.